# agreement how a Matrix (2D) is stored as JSON?

Tags: json, matlab, octave

Is there some agreement on how a Matrix should be stored as JSON from math software like Matlab/Octave/R?

For example

```
a =
    1   2
    3   4
```

can be saved as (and it's my favourite because it's fortran order):

```
{"a":[[1,3],[2,4]]}
```

Another way (this is what [jsonlab](https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab/) would do):

```
{"a":[[1,2],[3,4]]}
```

But is there some agreement/common sense under JSON user?

Comment: I would guess the second makes more sense, and is also compatible with python array syntax ... but wouldn't this be application specific anyway?

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou the first would be the natural way to implement it in GNU Octave but of course I want to be compatible with other software if possible. For the second I have to permute the first 2 dimensions after reading. No big deal to be "mainstream compatible", though. Ah, and if you say the second is how python it would do, then this is another good argument for it

Comment: The first one doesn't make sense to me though, even if it _can_ be unpacked more usefully in octave. The second (and presumably why numpy does it this way) feels more natural, since each 'nesting level' is another dimension. But I still think this would by highly implementation specific; the json could well have been an object with a 'size' and 'data' argument, which holds the data as a linear array and 'reshapes' as necessary. In fact, isn't that what octave does with its text format when you `save`?

Comment: The second is also used in the R jsonlite package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html. @Tasos Papastylianou - i'm not sure what you mean by each nesting level is another dimension? Doesn't that apply to both?

Comment: @stephematician well, yes, but not in a meaningful order. I meant that, as far as it is convention to treat rows as the first dimension, and columns as the 2nd, then the 'top' alternative nests dimensions in the following order: 2, 1, 3, 4 .. etc. The argument _for_ this syntax would be that octave uses column-major-order, hence this format is more 'natural' to octave and would lead to better efficiency. But the argument _against_ it would be that it's more meaningful and consistent to have each dimension as a nested level (i.e. 1st, then 2nd, then 3rd, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the second format is clearly preferred. Each of

- [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html) - a (popular?) javascript library which supports matrices,
- [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html) - an R package which can encode/decode matrices (note that rjson and rjsonio don't seem to do this so well), and
- [json-tricks](http://json-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/numpy) -python/numpy json package

all declare matrices in the second format you suggest, in addition to jsonlab which you have mentioned.